# Google Map with red hue - via Javascript API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using jquery-ui-map to show a Google Map on my webpage via the Javascript API.

I want to give the whole map a hue of #ff0000, but I'm not entirely sure how to implement that into the Javascript code I'm using currently.

How do I do that?

```
        $(function() { 
            demo.add(function() {


                $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': '57.7973333,12.0502107', 'zoom': 10, 'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
                    var self = this;
                    self.addMarker({'position': this.get('map').getCenter() }).click(function() {
                        self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': 'Hello World!' }, this);
                    }); 
                }});
            }).load();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

gmap has a **backgroundColor** attribute,I think what you want is like this

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({'backgroundColor':#ff0000,'center': '57.7973333,12.0502107', 'zoom': 10,  'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function(){}
```

if not you can refer to Google maps api about MapOptions.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

Comment: it seems like the attribute I actually want is not apart of "MapOptions", but "MapTypeStyler" instead. I'm looking to set the parameter for hue, apart of "MapTypeStyler".

Trying to set hue in the line of code you've set out above doesn't work either.